# Cannot use object of type Zend\InputFilter\Input as array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework, zend-inputfilter

I'd like to to cacth a error messages from inputfilter:

```
foreach ($pool->getInputFilter()->getInvalidInput() as $error) {

     $errors[$error["'".$error->getName()."'"]] = '$error->getMessages();
     print_r($error->getMessages());
     print_r($error->getName());
     print_r("<br />");
    //array_push($errors,$error);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  You probably want to be looping through `$pool`.

Comment: "$error->getMessage()" returns an array "[isEmpty]=>My message".

Comment: with $errors= array(); $errors[$error['"'.$error['"'.$error->getName().'"']] = $error->getMessage(); don't work because getMessage() returns an array and with getMessage()['isEmpty'] or getMessage()->isEmpty  is unsuccessful.

Comment: "Cannot use object of type Zend\InputFilter\Input as array"

Answer (score 0):

There's `getErrorMessage` method on each input in inputFilter. So correct example can be somethink like:

```
/** @var \Zend\InputFilter\InputInterface $input */

foreach ($inputFilter->getInvalidInput() as $input) {
      echo $input->getErrorMessage();
}
```